# Pi b+ power issues?

Tags: power-supply, usb-power

I have a raspberry pi b+ with raspbian stretch. My power adapter is rated at 5v 1.5 amp. I have a monitor and network cable connected, USB keyboard, USB mouse and 2 USB cameras connected via the 4 USB ports.  When I boot up the pi, a lightning bolt appears in the top right. And raspbian keeps randomly crashing, especially when I play videos. Would using a powered usb hub solve the issue? Or must I get shorter better quality usb cables?

Comment: See [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)

Answer (score 0):

you can check the power consumption of USB devices like this: https://superuser.com/questions/297959/how-do-you-check-how-much-power-a-usb-port-can-deliver, or for the long version type lsusb -v. it sounds like a powered usb hub would help. the dc adapter on the wall connector would be a bigger issue than the cables themselves.